# When I try to add the intl dependenceis on my flutter project I got error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-lints

flutter pub get --intl: ^0.19.0
Resolving dependencies...
Error on line 42, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
╷
42 │ ┌     sdk: flutter
43 │ │     intl: ^0.19.0
44 │ │
45 │ │
46 │ │   # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
47 │ │   # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
48 │ │   # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
49 │ │   # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
50 │ │   # rules and activating additional ones.
51 │ │   flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
│ └──^

i try to install new version it will show me the date time month

this is my pubspec.yaml file-

```
name: basics
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    intl: ^0.19.0
    

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: FontMain
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/BodoniModa-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that you are using a YAML file and the indentation is important here. Now, the `intl` dependency belongs to the flutter_test parameters' list which is wrong.

Thus, you can resolve the issue by fixing the indentation like this:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.19.0
```

Also, based on the documentation, you should probably add the `intl` to the `dependencies` section rather than `dev_dependencies` - double-check it:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.19.0
```

Comment: The OP added the package in `dev_dependencies` and you didn't describe or at list give a reference why it is required to be in `dependencies` and why it is not working another way. :)

Comment: @Warjeh As it was described in your now deleted response (the argument was valid, so why, though?), it probably does not make much sense to keep it only under the `dev_dependencies`. Anyway, I updated the response to make all the parties happy. Cheers!

Comment: I had a problem with downvoting where the solution I was made was exactly answering the error code, nothing more or less. :D

Comment: Then you make the adjustments, we update the vote. It's all about helping the community and not caring about the fake fame points.

Comment: I know your answer is right, and I care enough to test every answer that I make in my local machine. But I have a problem with people downvoting an answer, and repost that answer with some slight modification to get the accepted answer. That is why I wasn't much active in this site. And I think that was my first downvote in all these years. :)) I'm ok now.